# My Bitcoin-QT directories are empty? (Ubuntu)

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, linux, ubuntu

According to Bitcoin-QT (I am using the snap store version) my Datadir is

*/home/(username)/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin*

and my Blocksdir is

*home/(username)/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/blocks*.

However, when I navigate to *home/(username)/snap/bitcoin-core/common* the directory appears to be empty. Are the files hidden or something?

I ask because I need to move that stuff over to an external drive and point Bitcoin-QT to look for it there.

Also, when I go into settings and click "open configuration file" nothing happens.

When it's open Bitcoin-QT just starts syncing away. It's working fine. But I can't figure out where the data is going! Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In linux files and directories that start with a dot(.) are hidden by default. Inside ‘ home/(username)/snap/bitcoin-core/common’ try using ‘ls -la’ and you should be able to list hidden files or directories, in this case ‘.bitcoin’, hope this help!